# Select row with most recent date by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R where the rows represent events, and one column is the date of the event. The thing the event is happening to is described by an ID column. So for each ID there are multiple entries.

How do I filter the data frame so that I retain only the most recent event for each ID? The IDs are integers and the dates are in the form `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID= rep(1:3, each=3), date=c('02/20/1989',
'03/14/2001', '02/25/1990',  '04/20/2002', '02/04/2005', '02/01/2008',
'08/22/2011','08/20/2009', '08/25/2010' ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: How to do this but also taking into consideration hours, minutes and seconds? I have some registers with the same month, day, year, hour and minutes but different seconds and i'm not able to obtain the most recent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kikusanchez you may have to convert to POSIXct with `as.POSIXct` and specify the format as in the order

Comment: Should be noted that because `which.max` returns the *first* max it comes across in a group, if you have duplicated dates you may have problems. Look at `dplyr::slice_max(date, with_ties=TRUE)` if you want to keep duplicate dates.

Comment: @nstjhp yes, but with `slice_max` there is also another issue.  Suppose if you have only one value and the number of rows is 10000, with_ties, will print all those 10000 lines

Comment: @akrun quite so, just wanted to raise this in case it would help anyone.

Answer (score 12):

For any solution, you might as well correct your date variable first, as shown by @akrun:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

**Base R**

```
df[
  tapply(1:nrow(df),df$ID,function(ii) ii[which.max(df$date[ii])])
,]
```

This uses a selection of row numbers to subset the data. You can see the selection by running the middle line (between the `[]`s) on its own.

**Data.table**

Similar to @rawr's:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

unique(DT[order(date)], by="ID", fromLast=TRUE)
# or
unique(DT[order(-date)], by="ID")
```

Comment: That's a pretty interesting base R `tapply` solution. I'm not sure I've recognized it before.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can order the dates and

```
df <- data.frame(ID= rep(1:3, each=3), date=c('02/20/1989',
                                              '03/14/2001', '02/25/1990',  '04/20/2002', '02/04/2005', '02/01/2008',
                                              '08/22/2011','08/20/2009', '08/25/2010' ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y')

## make sure to order by both `ID` and `date` as Frank mentions in comments
## since the dates may be overlapping among IDs

df <- df[with(df, order(ID, date)), ]
```

1) select the last

```
df[cumsum(table(df$ID)), ]

#   ID       date
# 2  1 2001-03-14
# 6  2 2008-02-01
# 7  3 2011-08-22
```

2) or remove the duplicates

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE), ]

#   ID       date
# 2  1 2001-03-14
# 6  2 2008-02-01
# 7  3 2011-08-22
```

this data brought to you by @akrun

Comment: Safer to `order(df$ID,df$date)` since `ID`s might not partition dates into nonoverlapping intervals.

Comment: @Frank werd. I thought I did that, good catch. It's a shame that it worked without doing that, otherwise I wouldnt have caught it

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a character flaw but I sometimes resist picking up new packages. The "base R" functions can often do the job. In this case I think the alue of the `dplyr` package shows through since I stumbled in creating a good solution since the `ave` function returned a character value for a logical test, which I still don't understand. So I think dplyr is a real gem. And if I could I'd like to insist that any upvotes be preceded by an upvote to akrun's answer. (It's hard to believe this hasn't already been asked and answered on SO.)

Anyway:

```
> df[ as.logical(
        ave(df$date, df$ID, FUN=function(d) as.Date(d , '%m/%d/%Y') == 
                                             max(as.Date(d, '%m/%d/%Y'))))
      , ]
  ID       date
2  1 03/14/2001
6  2 02/01/2008
7  3 08/22/2011
```

I thought this should work  (fail) :

```
> df[ ave(df$date, df$ID, FUN=function(d) as.Date(d , '%m/%d/%Y') ==max(as.Date(d, '%m/%d/%Y'))) , ]
     ID date
NA   NA <NA>
NA.1 NA <NA>
NA.2 NA <NA>
NA.3 NA <NA>
NA.4 NA <NA>
NA.5 NA <NA>
NA.6 NA <NA>
NA.7 NA <NA>
NA.8 NA <NA>
```

Here's another base R solution that worked the first time with no surprises:

```
> do.call( rbind, by(df, df$ID, function(d) d[ which.max(as.Date(d$date, '%m/%d/%Y')), ] ) )
  ID       date
1  1 03/14/2001
2  2 02/01/2008
3  3 08/22/2011
```

Here's one inspired by @rawr's notion of taking the last one from an ordered subset:

```
> do.call( rbind, by(df, df$ID, function(d) tail( d[ order(as.Date(d$date, '%m/%d/%Y')), ] ,1)) )
  ID       date
1  1 03/14/2001
2  2 02/01/2008
3  3 08/22/2011
```

Comment: Weird. `ave` doesn't like to report results in the correct mode. Neither of these gives logical: `ave(c("a","b"),1,FUN=function(x)x==x[1])` or `ave(c(1,2),1,FUN=function(x)x==x[1])`

Answer (score 0):

I've never processed any data in R without `plyr`!

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID), summarize, most_recent = max(as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')))

   ID most_recent
1  1  2001-03-14
2  2  2008-02-01
3  3  2011-08-22
```

Comment: This returns two columns: "ID" and "most-recent".
How can I keep the rest of the columns too?