# How to select 'x' most recent values in each group in R?

Tags: r, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select/filter the most recent values in each group in a data frame in R. For example, I would like to select the 3 most recent (i.e. the dates closest to today) from each Name group in the following data frame:

```
Player  Date    Result
 Sam    03/15/2015  1
 Sam    03/22/2015  0
 Sam    04/04/2015  2
 Sam    04/12/2015  1
 Sam    04/18/2015  1
 Sam    04/26/2015  0
 Sam    08/08/2015  3
Steve   02/17/2015  0
Steve   02/21/2015  0
Steve   03/04/2015  4
Steve   03/11/2015  2
Steve   03/15/2015  1
Steve   03/22/2015  0
Steve   04/12/2015  0
Steve   04/18/2015  2
Steve   04/26/2015  1
Steve   04/29/2015  2
Steve   08/16/2015  4
Jasper  03/15/2015  3
Jasper  03/22/2015  3.5
Jasper  04/04/2015  4
Jasper  04/12/2015  4
Jasper  04/18/2015  5
Jasper  04/26/2015  0
```

I have written `as.date()` code so R now understands the date format but what code can I now use to only select the 3 (say) most recent values from each group?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? Why did it not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain only the most recent date for every ID in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058708/retain-only-the-most-recent-date-for-every-id-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class by using `as.Date`.  After grouping by 'Player', we `arrange` the 'Date' column descendingly and use `slice` to get the most recent 3 values.  If we don't want to change the 'Date' class, we can remove the `mutate` step and do the conversion within the `arrange` i.e. `arrange(desc(as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')))`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date=as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
    group_by(Player) %>% 
    arrange(desc(Date)) %>% 
    slice(1:3)
#    Player       Date Result
#1 Jasper 2015-04-26      0
#2 Jasper 2015-04-18      5
#3 Jasper 2015-04-12      4
#4    Sam 2015-08-08      3
#5    Sam 2015-04-26      0
#6    Sam 2015-04-18      1
#7  Steve 2015-08-16      4
#8  Steve 2015-04-29      2
#9  Steve 2015-04-26      1
```

Or after we group by the 'Player', we can use `top_n` by specifying the 'n' and the 'wt' variable for ordering.

```
 df1 %>% 
   mutate(Date=as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
   group_by(Player)  %>%
   top_n(n = 3, Date)
#  Player       Date Result
#1    Sam 2015-04-18      1
#2    Sam 2015-04-26      0
#3    Sam 2015-08-08      3
#4  Steve 2015-04-26      1
#5  Steve 2015-04-29      2
#6  Steve 2015-08-16      4
#7 Jasper 2015-04-12      4
#8 Jasper 2015-04-18      5
#9 Jasper 2015-04-26      0
```

---

Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by the 'Player, we `order` the 'Date' after converting to `Date` class, and using the `head` we can get the first 3 rows of each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-as.IDate(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')),head(.SD, 3) , by = Player]
#   Player       Date Result
#1:  Steve 08/16/2015      4
#2:  Steve 04/29/2015      2
#3:  Steve 04/26/2015      1
#4:    Sam 08/08/2015      3
#5:    Sam 04/26/2015      0
#6:    Sam 04/18/2015      1
#7: Jasper 04/26/2015      0
#8: Jasper 04/18/2015      5
#9: Jasper 04/12/2015      4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Player = c("Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", 
"Sam", "Sam", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", 
"Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Jasper", "Jasper", 
"Jasper", "Jasper", "Jasper", "Jasper"), Date = c("03/15/2015", 
"03/22/2015", "04/04/2015", "04/12/2015", "04/18/2015", "04/26/2015", 
"08/08/2015", "02/17/2015", "02/21/2015", "03/04/2015", "03/11/2015", 
"03/15/2015", "03/22/2015", "04/12/2015", "04/18/2015", "04/26/2015", 
"04/29/2015", "08/16/2015", "03/15/2015", "03/22/2015", "04/04/2015", 
"04/12/2015", "04/18/2015", "04/26/2015"), Result = c(1, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3.5, 4, 4, 5, 
0)), .Names = c("Player", "Date", "Result"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -24L))
```

Comment: This solution looks great, thanks so much! I will be able to test it properly in a few days, and will report back to confirm.

Comment: I went with the top_n and it worked great. What's nice is it doesn't give an Error Message if one of the group lengths is less than 'n'. It just includes whatever observations are available for that group.

Comment: @WillT-E Thanks for the feedback.  `slice` also should work in that way.  For example `df1 %>%mutate(Date=as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%  group_by(Player) %>% arrange(desc(Date)) %>% slice(1:7)`