# Applying slice() to a tbl

Tags: r, dplyr

In dplyr, when I use the function slice() on a tbl (postgres database), I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("slice_") : no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

I don't want to convert my tbl to a data frame since it's large. Is there a way that I can apply slice to tbl or an alternative command?

Comment: It needs to be a `tbl_df` then.  The two `slice_` methods are for `data.frame` and `tbl_df`.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't want to use either object types since my dataset is large.  Is there an equivalent for slice for SQL?

Comment: This is why I need to use slice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058708/retain-only-the-most-recent-date-for-every-id-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no slice command interface with SQL. The reason is because, depending on your implementation, it involves specifying a WHERE statement unique to PostgreSQL. More Information: https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr

So for your question, a better option may be to run:

```
head(tbl, n = 20)
```

That should work.