# Select only the most recent POSIXlt date/time

Tags: r

This is similar to this question: [Retain only the most recent date for every ID in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058708/retain-only-the-most-recent-date-for-every-id-in-a-data-frame).

The difference ist, that i am using a %Y%m%d%H%M format, so date plus time. The exact time is important in this example.

We might use the following data frame and approach as a very much shortened example:

```
Event <- rep(1, 3)
Location <- c("a", "b", "c")
Date <- c(181905101300, 181905101453, 181905101613)

(df <- data.frame(Event, Location, Date))

  Event Location         Date
1     1        a 181905101300
2     1        b 181905101453
3     1        c 181905101613

(df %>% 
  group_by(Event) %>%
  dplyr::slice(which.max(Date)))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   Event [1]
  Event Location         Date
  <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1     1 c        181905101613
```

Usually i am working with the following format though:

```
(df$Date <- strptime(df$Date, format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))

[1] "1819-05-10 13:00:00 LMT" "1819-05-10 14:53:00 LMT" "1819-05-10 16:13:00 LMT"
```

How can i achieve the same result with this format? Is it possible? I tried "dplyr::slice" but it seems to be having problems with POSIXlt.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using `POSIXlt`. If you switch to `POSIXct`, things should be fine. As the answer shows, the `lubridate` package makes this easy.

Comment: Use `df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)` after `strptime()`, and your method will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use lubridate in this case

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Event <- c(1,1,2)
Location <- c("a", "b", "c")
Date <- c(181905101300, 181905101453, 181905101613)

df <- data.frame(Event, Location, Date)

df %>% 
  mutate(time_hour = ymd_hm(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Event) %>%
  top_n(1,wt = time_hour)
```