# R Select latest date row for each individual

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with values such as:

```
    Individual     Date            Score
      A          2019/07/01         10
      A          2019/06/01         5
      B          2019/06/01         8
      C          2019/08/01         8
      C          2019/06/01         5
```

I want to filter to have just the latest score for each individual.

```
    Individual     Date            Score
      A          2019/07/01         10
      B          2019/06/01         8
      C          2019/08/01         8
```

I'm not sure the most efficient way of achieving this.

Thank you for any help

Comment: [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058708/retain-only-the-most-recent-date-for-every-id-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your data is stored in a data.frame named `df`. We could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Individual) %>%
  slice_max(Date)
```

which results in

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Individual [3]
  Individual Date       Score
  <chr>      <date>     <dbl>
1 A          2019-07-01    10
2 B          2019-06-01     8
3 C          2019-08-01     8
```

Comment: I have the dplyr library installed but it says it can't find the function slice_max

Comment: You need the latest (as of today 2020-06-22) version, 1.0.0

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy amendment if there are multiple types of score, and you want to keep one row for each combination of individual and score type for the latest date?

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(as.IDate(Date))], Individual]
#   Individual       Date Score
#1:          A 2019/07/01    10
#2:          B 2019/06/01     8
#3:          C 2019/08/01     8
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Individual = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("2019/06/01", "2019/07/01", "2019/08/01"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(10L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I'm somehow not comfortable with data.table's structure and syntax. Is it useful for small datasets?

Comment: @MartinGal You can use it any datasets, whether small or large.  With large datasets, you may find the significant difference in efficiency.  I guess you question would be whether there is any drop in efficiency with data.table.  With small datasets, I don't find it because both base R or data.table or dplyr would give similar timings.  Of course, it would be up to the user to whether install an external package or not

Answer (score 1):

in Base R

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Individual), function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(x$Date)),]))

  Individual       Date Score
A          A 2019/07/01    10
B          B 2019/06/01     8
C          C 2019/08/01     8
```

or if the dates are already in order always we can simplify to

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Individual), function(x) x[1,]))
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Individual = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("2019/06/01", "2019/07/01", "2019/08/01"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(10L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R alternative

```
index <- tapply(1:nrow(df), df$Individual, function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(df[x, "Date"]))])
df[index, ]

  Individual       Date Score
1          A 2019/07/01    10
3          B 2019/06/01     8
4          C 2019/08/01     8
```

You can use this workflow with multiple grouping variables as well; just replace the second argument to `tapply` with the subset of variables you are wanting to group by (e.g., `df[c("Individual", "Type")]`, as opposed to `df$Individual`).