# Select latest row from duplicates based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

In the following data frame, there are duplicates based on two columns: year (int) and legal_entity_registration_nr (int).

```
structure(list(file_id = c(20045467L, 20057886L, 21624801L, 21624810L, 
14889735L, 14889737L), legal_entity_registration_number = c(40003032949, 
40003032949, 40003032949, 40003032949, 40003032949, 40003032949
), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2008L, 2008L), employees = c(1431L, 
3908L, 1355L, 3508L, 1380L, 5378L), currency = c("EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "LVL", "LVL"), rounded_to_nearest = c("THOUSANDS", 
"THOUSANDS", "THOUSANDS", "THOUSANDS", "ONES", "ONES"), created_at = structure(c(1604730505, 
1604732566, 1605357231, 1605357235, 1597335737, 1609340436), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

From this there are duplicates, and the value of the latest one is needed, based on: created_at (date and time format).

In this case the result would be the following:

```
structure(list(file_id = c(14889737L, 20057886L, 21624810L), 
    legal_entity_registration_number = c(40003032949, 40003032949, 
    40003032949), year = c(2008L, 2017L, 2018L), employees = c(5378L, 
    3908L, 3508L), currency = c("LVL", "EUR", "EUR"), rounded_to_nearest = c("ONES", 
    "THOUSANDS", "THOUSANDS"), created_at = structure(c(1609340436, 
    1604732566, 1605357235), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2008L, 
2017L, 2018L), legal_entity_registration_number = c(40003032949, 
40003032949, 40003032949), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Thanks in advance.

Using the duplicated() formula been able to select the duplicated observations, yet not the list of all the other values. Can't figure out how to separate the duplicates from the data frame and select the latest one from the duplicates, without taking away the other columns.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058708/select-row-with-most-recent-date-by-group

Comment: almost certainly a case for `group_by(year, legal_entity_registration_nr) %>% slice_max(order_by = desc(created_at), with_ties=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, r2evans's answer works perfectly (edited for brevity):

```
dplyr::slice_max(df, order_by = desc(created_at), with_ties = FALSE, by = c(year, legal_entity_registration_number))
```

Output:

```
   file_id legal_entity_registration_number year employees currency
1 20045467                      40003032949 2017      1431      EUR
2 21624801                      40003032949 2018      1355      EUR
3 14889735                      40003032949 2008      1380      LVL
  rounded_to_nearest          created_at
1          THOUSANDS 2020-11-07 17:28:25
2          THOUSANDS 2020-11-14 23:33:51
3               ONES 2020-08-14 02:22:17
```

In your desired output though, even though you *say* you want the latest one, you chose the earlier one in all rows. If you *actually* want the earlier one, then it's simple to get that instead- just replace `desc(created_at)` with `created_at`, or replace `slice_max` with `slice_min`